# Sensors and webpages

Tags: http, 3d

I wonder if you wonderful people can point me in the right direction??

I'm quite new to web programming, I'm OK at conventional C/C++ etc but just really getting into the whole webside thang. Anyway, I was wondering how I may solve the following.

I want to have a sensor (doesn't matter what type it is, let's say a temperature sensor). This sensor will read it's environment reporting on (in this case) temperature. (Let's say the circuitry has been built and it's giving the data I need - via a desktop app)

My question is

- List item I want to convert the sensor output to a 3D graph (any ideas guys),
  I want to be able to show the graph on PC/smartphones (so think a web interface the best approach - unless someone/anyone has better ideas and most importantly links)
- List item I want to show the temperature change/graph in 'real time' (absolutely crucial) through the web interface .

I think, the conversion of the data would have to be done server-side. I'm thinking (and I may be wrong so please do correct)

- List item Client side - Get sensor data (via the desktop app)
- List item Client side - Transmit data (via the desktop app - not sure how this would be done yet)
- List item Server side - Convert data to graph
- List item Server side - Transmit data/graph
- List item Client side - Receive data
- List item Client side - Show graph

If this were just a question of rendering a sensors data to a PC screen (self contained application) - I would feel confident to tackle it. However, I think where I'm getting stuck is the rendering/transmitting and displaying of the 3D images in real time using web technology, platforms and languages. If it helps, I am just picking up Php, MySql and python. I already know C/C++/VB and assembly.

I hope this makes sense, any starting points that you can give will be greatly appreciated
Jason :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use MRTG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Router_Traffic_Grapher
It provides real time and png graphics of sensor data.
It is very easy to configure and shows/records tipical 1 year of data in a RRD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database

Comment: Hi @cfreire,thanks for the reply, I'll certainly check these out